# Maximum time period for a flagged question to get reviewed by a moderator

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, vote-to-close

I have flagged [Google image search in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719424/google-image-search-in-objective-c) as duplicate more than a week ago (on 18 May 2014), but the status still says **active**.

What's the maximum time period for a flagged question to get reviewed? Is there any automated system for it?

Comment: There's about 9 thousand posts in the close review queue. Reviews are done by humans (well, mostly humans), so the time it takes is unpredictable.

Comment: but except this almost all the question get reviewed within max of 2-3 hours time period.

Comment: Different flags get handled by different groups. Close flags go into the close vote review queue, which is large. 'Other' flags go to diamond moderators, whom also have a big pile to deal with. **It depends**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is there any way , i can appeal moderator to remove my flag, because for this particular question , i was totally wrong.

Comment: And May 18th is **not** long ago, really.

Comment: Nope, flags cannot be retracted. Leave it to the review queue, they'll either vote 'leave open' or close it anyway.

Comment: In the meantime, the question has been closed already.

Comment: Handled, although I don't want to encourage you to post on Meta every time a flag takes a week to be reviewed. Also, note that moderators aren't looking at flags to close. They go into the review queue.

Comment: wow! really a quick reply.

Comment: @JoshCaswell no i will not do it. i just want to know the process for how the flag get reviewed & is there any way to correct my mistake.

Comment: [flag to close can linger for months](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203670/dont-let-flag-to-close-flags-linger-for-months-in-flag-purgatory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no maximum length of time a flag can be active for.

It all depends on when (or if) someone - be it a diamond moderator or, in the case of close flags, any user with more than 3,000 reputation comes across it and decides to act on it.

It may be that the flag never gets acted upon but this is unlikely.